# Laravel HasMany query latest entry and return related model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship, laravel-8

Using Laravel 8

I have 3 models (Album, Track, Playcount). One Album has many Tracks, and one track has many Playcounts (every 24 hours a job will run and update the playcount).

Album Model

```
public function playcounts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Playcount', 'App\Models\Track');
}
```

Track Model

```
public function playcounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Playcount::class, 'track_id');
}
```

Playcount Model

```
public function track()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Track::class);
}
```

I would like to be able to select all albums where the **LATEST** entry in the playcounts table is older than 24 hours. Been stuck on this for days.
What I'm trying right now is this:

Playcount Model

```
public function latest_playcount()
    {
        return $this->playcounts()->latest()->first();
    }
```

Controller

```
$track = Track::whereHas('playcounts', function($q) {
    $q->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subHour(24));
        })
        ->with('playcounts')
        ->first();

$album_id = $track->album_id; //after this, select the album
```

is it possible to do this in one query?

Any help with this much appreciated.

**EDIT:** should anyone ever run into something similar, i solved it this way:

```
$album = DB::table('playcounts as p')
          ->select('p.*')
          ->leftJoin('playcounts as p1', function ($join) {
                $join->on('p.track_id', '=', 'p1.track_id')
                     ->whereRaw(DB::raw('p.created_at < p1.created_at'));
           })
          ->whereNull('p1.track_id')
          ->where('p.created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subHours(24))
                  ->join('tracks', 'tracks.id', 'p.track_id')
                    ->join('albums', 'albums.id', 'tracks.album_id')
                    ->addSelect('albums.*')
                    ->groupBy('albums.id')
                  ->take(1)->get();
```

Thank you everybody for helping!

Comment: Why don't you start with playcounts and walk back to albums?

Comment: I don't know if I understood it correctly, you want the albums that have been played in the last 24 hours?

Comment: Hello Artur, I want all albums which has tracks which have a LATEST entry in the playcounts table that is older than 24h. The problem is identifying only the LATEST entry for each track

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, have you tried this?

I've made assumptions that your tables are named:
`tracks`,
`albums`,
`playcounts`

And that they all have the column names, I've listed.

```
use DB;

$albums = Playcount::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDay())
    ->join('tracks', 'tracks.id', 'playcounts.track_id')
    ->join('albums', 'albums.id', 'tracks.album_id')
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('albums.*, SUM(playcounts.value)'))
    ->groupBy('albums.id')
    ->get();
```

Of course, you can walk the other way, but this is simple. I'm not sure if you'll have dupes because of the 1 to many tracks -> albums relation, but the groupBy will solve that.

Comment: Thank you so much Ballard, this is one of the directions I have tried previously (told you, been going crazy over this for some time :-) ) 
Here the problem is that it will take just the first entry in the playcounts table - also, if there is already have a newer entry. the problem is identifying the latest playcount

Comment: I've rebuilt your data structure and ran that query myself, I get multiple albums back out with a SUM of the play count for each track in that album

Comment: It is also highly likely that you made a typo in your question and in fact you want records LESS THAN or NEWER than 24 hours ago, if that is the case `where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDay())` becomes `where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())`

Comment: Also, replace `playcounts.value` with the field_name you store your counts in

Comment: Hello Ballard, no I'm sure it needs to be older than 24 hours :-)

look in my playcounts table let's say i have 2 entries for 1 track

ID track_id playcount         created_at
1 1  100   2020-10-16 14:28:11
2 1  200   2020-10-17 14:28:11

how can i ONLY select id=2 (because created_at is newer than the other) and then check if the created_at is older than 24 hours?